# thrown exception AS-WEB-CORE-00089 on forwarding to a different servlet path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I was trying to forward from doPost to doGet of the ControllerServlet urlPattern = "/remove_person", so I can re-update findAll query inside my doGet method of the ControllerServlet class, and then forward to remove_person.jsp from doGet method, but AS-WEB-CORE-00089 exception is thrown

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[ControllerServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ControllerServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: AS-WEB-CORE-00089
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:863)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at server.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:130)
```

where ControllerServlet.java:130 line is in doPost() method:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
```

Here is the code of servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "ControllerServlet", 
    loadOnStartup = 1,
    urlPatterns = {
        "/index", 
        "/search_person", 
        "/add_person",
        "/remove_person"})
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        assert emf != null;
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();

        if (servletPath.equals("/index")) {
        }
        else if (servletPath.equals("/search_person")) {
            List persons = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll").getResultList();
            request.setAttribute("findByNameAndYearBirth", persons);
        }
        else if (servletPath.equals("/add_person")) {
        }
        else if (servletPath.equals("/remove_person")) {
            List persons = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll").getResultList();
            request.setAttribute("findAll", persons);
        }
        String url = servletPath + ".jsp";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();

        if (servletPath.equals("/index")) {
        }
        else if (servletPath.equals("/search_person")) {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String yearBirth = request.getParameter("yearBirth");

            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll");
            if (!name.isEmpty() && !yearBirth.isEmpty()) {
                query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByNameAndYearBirth");
                query.setParameter("name", name);
                query.setParameter("yearBirth", Short.parseShort(yearBirth));
            }
            else if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByModel");
                query.setParameter("name", name);
            }
            else if (!yearBirth.isEmpty()) {
                try  {
                    Short sYearBirth = Short.parseShort(yearBirth);
                    query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByYearBirth");
                    query.setParameter("yearBirth", sYearBirth);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
            }
            List persons = query.getResultList();
            request.setAttribute("findByNameAndYearBirth", persons);
        }
        else if (servletPath.equals("/add_person")) {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String hobby = request.getParameter("hobby");
            String yearBirth = request.getParameter("yearBirth");

            int personsLen = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll").getResultList().size();
            Person newPerson = new Person(
                ++personsLen, name, hobby, Short.parseShort(yearBirth)
            );
            try {
                utx.begin();
                em = emf.createEntityManager();
                em.persist(newPerson);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if (servletPath.equals("/remove_person")) {
            String id = request.getParameter("id");

            Person person = null;  
            try {
                utx.begin();
                person = em.find(Person.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
                em.remove(person);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            servletPath = "/remove_person";
        }
        String url = servletPath;
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Problem is, my line inside doPost method

```
String url = path;
```

does not contain a ".jsp" part.

But if I add ".jsp" part to a string url, then how I will update findAll query data inside remove_person.jsp if i don't go to servlet doGet first to collect new data after adding or deleting entities?

remove_person.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Remove Person</h1>
        <form action="remove_person" method="post">
            <table border="3">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach var="person" begin="0" items="${findAll}"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>${person.id}</td> 
                        <td>${person.name}</td> 
                    </tr> 
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
            <strong>Remove person: </strong>
            <select name="id">
            <c:forEach var="person" items="${findAll}">
                <option value="${person.id}">${person.id}. ${person.name} </option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" id="remove_person" value="Remove" />
        </form>
        <br>
        <a href="index">Home page</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Actually, is it even possible to forward from doPost to doGet method of the same servlet ? The reason I was trying to do this is because, inside doGet I already use this code:

```
List persons = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll").getResultList();
request.setAttribute("findAll", persons);
```

So why should I duplicate this code inside doPost method, when I can forward from doPost to doGet method and invoke that code?

**UPDATE:**

Bad approach:

```
String url = servletPath;
request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
```

Correct approach:

```
String url = request.getContextPath() + servletPath;
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use redirect instead of forward. The pattern (called [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)) is:

1) the client calls the post url, which does your update

2) the servlet sends a redirect to the client with the url for the get.

3) the client calls the url from the redirect.

When the response from the GET comes back the browser has the GET url, so the browser ends up with a url that's bookmarkable. Also this way the user can't repost the same data by hitting f5 or clicking multiple times.

For when to use forward vs redirect see [this advice](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181):

> Forward
>
> - a forward is performed internally by the servlet
> - the browser is completely unaware that it has taken place, so its original URL remains intact
> - any browser reload of the resulting page will simple repeat the original request, with the original URL
>
> Redirect
>
> - a redirect is a two step process, where the web application instructs the browser to fetch a second URL, which differs from the
>     original
> - a browser reload of the second URL will not repeat the original request, but will rather fetch the second URL
> - redirect is marginally slower than a forward, since it requires two browser requests, not one
> - objects placed in the original request scope are not available to the second request
>
> In general, a forward should be used if the operation can be safely repeated upon a browser reload of the resulting web page; otherwise, redirect must be used. Typically, if the operation performs an edit on the datastore, then a redirect, not a forward, is required. This is simply to avoid the possibility of inadvertently duplicating an edit to the database.

Comment: This is it! Thank you Nathan Hughes